# Android: Calling images of different size

Tags: javascript, android, html, performance, jquery-ui

Hi I am making app to works on all devices tables

My main concerns are:

1. There are lots of images in my pages , images are of large size as they need to look good in tablet also
   But for mobile device pages gets heavy and app hangs
   Is there any way to call different Images based on device (the way android does using drawable folder). I am calling Image reference like `<IMG SRC="">`
2. How can I set memory heap to large as we do in manifest. XML
3. How can I make my app faster ?

Answer (score 0):

1: how can I set memory heap to large as we do in manifest. XML
Ans:
Give those permission in manifest to handle the memory management.

android:vmSafeMode="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

2: how can I make my app faster ?
Ans: use lazy loading for images or use universal-image-loader-1.8.6-with-sources.jar to show the images.This jar load your images once then it will show from cache next time.

Comment: yeah where to set it i am using intel xdk

Comment: android:vmSafeMode="true" why ??

Answer (score -2):

You have to have multiple classes based on tablet and normal cell phones. And obviously you can check on which device your app is running and wheather it is running in landscape or potrait mode. To make your app faster use Picasso for image loading and also look at

Density-independent pixels (dp) are different than normal pixels (px).

9-patch drawables are stretched to fit the screen.

Comment: its html based app how to make multiple calsses , can u give some example or refernces

Comment: Sorry @mour I am not that sound in html else would have surely helped you but I have implemented this and it works